# Sending dataframe as parquet file directly to dropbox

Tags: file-upload, dropbox, parquet, dropbox-api, uploading

During my script I generate a dataframe which I want to upload as a parquet file directly to dropbox. I have managed to find such solution:

https://gist.github.com/MaxHalford/f17994c77bb775fdd04c9cd925e0b279

which helps me save a dataframe. However, I really want to send a parquet file directly.

The option which seemed intuitive to me:

```
fileToSave=tempDf.to_parquet('newFile.parquet')
upload_file(dbx, file_location, fileToSave)
```

but it throws

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

any idea how it could be done otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `fileToSave=tempDf.to_parquet('newFile.parquet')`, it saves the table in a local file called `newfile.parquet` and returns `None`

What you want to do instead is:

```
data = tempDf.to_parquet() #  bytes content of the parquet file
dbx.files_upload(
        f=data,
        path=path,
        mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode.overwrite
    )
```

This will convert the df into bytes (in memory) that you can then upload to dropbox.